# C#: Как объявить класс с общими методами и использовать его без объявления?

Tags: c#, классы, методы

Занимаюсь разработкой на C# и столкнулся с одной проблемой.
Для понимания, есть несколько форм, которые используют одни и те же методы. Для оптимизации этого было принято решение выделить методы в отдельный класс и обращаться к ним **через имя класса**. Основная проблема, с которой я столкнулся, это **необходимость объявлять** класс перед его использованием. Собственно, вопрос, каким образом необходимо оформить класс, чтобы можно было использовать его методы в других классах без объявления этого самого класса? Вот кусок моего класса, который нужно использовать как внешний:

```
namespace ObjectAdmin
{
    public static class CommonFunctions
    {
        public static string RoleCollectionToString(List<string> rList)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            rList.ForEach(r => result += r + "|");
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result)) result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1, 1);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

То есть, например, при обращении к методу

```
RoleCollectionToString(List<string> rList)
```

мне приходится объявлять класс **CommonFunctions**, а я хочу как-то так:

```
string someString = CommonFunctions.RoleCollectionToString(someList)
```

Comment: Вызывать ваше функцию так : RoleCollectionToString(List<string> rList) вместо CommonFunctions.RoleCollectionToString(someList) можно только если функция определена внутри класса из которого она вызывается. Иначе, представьте что у вас два класса имеют одинакоое название функции но разную функциональность, тогда какая функциональность должна выполниться?

Comment: @koks_rs Всё оказалось элементарнее чем я себе представлял, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: using static же, нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class CommonExtensions
{
    public static string RoleCollectionToString(this List<string> rList)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        rList.ForEach(r => result += r + "|");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result)) result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1, 1);
        return result;
    }
}

string someString = someList.RoleCollectionToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать импорт статических членов, если используете C# 6 и выше, вот небольшой пример, в котором мы импортируем статические члены Вашего класса и System.Linq.Enumerable:

```
using static ObjectAdmin.CommonFunctions;
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;

namespace SomeUsingCommonFunctions
{
    class Foo
    {
        void Bar()
        {
            var list = Range(0, 10).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
            var someString = RoleCollectionToString(list)
        }
    }
}
```